# Can I know if an email recipient downloaded a mail dropped file in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, mail-drop

I have send a large file with Mail.app with the "drop" feature and would like to know if a recipient downloaded it. Is it possible to have such a information?

Answer (score 2):

This information is not available without asking the recipient.